# RegEx to find text in parentheses with condition

Tags: regex

If I have a String with food ingredients such as (german list of ingredients in a product)

```
Sahne, Zucker, Molkerzeugnis, modifizierte Stärke, 
2.1% fettarmer Kakao, Speisegelatine (Rind), 
Kräuter (Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum), 
Emulgator: Mono- und Diglyceride von Speisefettsäuren, Milcheiweiß, Stickstoff.
```

**Option 1.**
I want to separate them into a list of ingredient split by comma (but not the comma inside the brackets) with the elements being:

```
Sahne
Zucker
Molkerzeugnis
modifizierte Stärke
2.1% fettarmer Kakao
Speisegelatine (Rind)
**Kräuter (Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum)**
Emulgator: Mono- und Diglyceride von Speisefettsäuren
Milcheiweiß
Stickstoff.
```

**Option 2.**
I want to use RegEx to replace only 'Kräuter (Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum)' with 'Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum' so that each of the ingredients inside the brackets is used as a separate element in the list. 
**If there are brackets that only contain words, but no comma, I want to leave them as they are.** Speisegelatine (Rind) should stay as it is. 
**If there are bracket that contains words separated by commas, I want to replace them.** 'Kräuter (Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum)' should be replaced with 'Dill, Zwiebellauch, Basilikum'. 
Then the list should look like this:

```
Sahne
Zucker
Molkerzeugnis
modifizierte Stärke
2.1% fettarmer Kakao
Speisegelatine (Rind)
**Dill
Zwiebellauch
Basilikum**
Emulgator: Mono- und Diglyceride von Speisefettsäuren
Milcheiweiß
Stickstoff.
```

Comment: Don't you want to have `spices` in the output? Try `\w+(?:\s*\([^\W\d_]+\))?`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW2K59/1). Is it in Python, by the way?

Comment: No because spices is too general and I need the specific ingredients (as much as that is possible at least). The example you gave me returns almost every word, when I leave out the ? it gives me 'gelatin (cattle)' and not 'spices (dill, basil)', but I want it the other way around :)

Comment: Please show your code and revise the "list of elements" you need to get. Also, provide exact pattern specifications.

Comment: I updated the main post and tried to explain it as much as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach can be modify the string such that words like `spices (dill, basil)` be replaced with `dill, basil`  [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XfLlqu/1/)

`\(((?:\w+,\s)+\w+)\)` would match with `(` followed by one or more occurence of `word followed by comma and space` and then a word and lastly followed by `)` and here contents inside the brackets are captured and would replace the original pharse

```
str1 = "gelatin (cattle), water, spices (dill, basil)"

mod_str = re.sub(r'\w+\s*?\(((?:\w+,\s)+\w+)\)', r'\1', str2)
mod_str
'gelatin (cattle), water, dill, basil'
```

And then you can do normal string split

```
mod_str.split(', ')
['gelatin (cattle)', 'water', 'dill', 'basil']
```

Another example

```
str2 = "gelatin (cattle), water, spices (dill, basil, test1, test2)"
Output: ['gelatin (cattle)', 'water', 'dill', 'basil', 'test1', 'test2']
```